# Compare domain blocking by iptables vs dnsmasq-/etc/hosts

Tags: iptables, dns, dnsmasq

I now use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), with a large /etc/hosts file obtained from Energized packs [https://energized.pro/#packs]. Some of these are quite large.

Trying to get info from the dnsmasq team, which is still using a [mailist](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/mailman/listinfo/dnsmasq-discuss), not a forum, has been impossible.

1a) Can someone walk me through how dnsmasq resolves an address?
1b) Is it: cache, /etc/hosts, then upstream DNS?
1c) Is /etc/hosts cached in memory in some way?
1d) If not is there a tool/solution that would allow me to reduce lookup latency?

2a) Would [iptable](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) filters be faster in blocking a large list of domains/urls [on the order of 150,000+]?
2b) Is there a way to store the huge filter list in memory so iptables is faster? I read something about [IPTables-IPv4-DBTarpit](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPTables::IPv4::DBTarpit).

3) Any advice on other tools with the least latency for blocking IP lookups of a huge list of IP addresses?

I have all this RAM and I'd like to use it.

Comment: Does this `dnsmasq` only serve as a caching DNS proxy with this blocking list or is it also an authoritative server for some local network?

Comment: Authoritative for a local network.

Answer (score 1):

Better than using `/etc/hosts` for `dnsmasq` is to create a configuration with lines like this

```
address=/some.adserver.com/127.0.0.1
```

You can include a generated blocking list file with

```
conf-file=...
```

in `dnsmasq`'s main configuration file.

If you search for keywords `dnsmasq adblock` you may find some detailed instructions.

The "energized" URL in your question also provides configuration files specific for `dnsmasq`.

Comment: I tried this first and it was CONSIDERABLY slower than using /etc/hosts. The dnsmasq cache is currently set to a max of 10000, so using the Energize dnsmasq would result in random segment fault error 4 (memory). As I understand it the latest version of dnsmasq uses hashing for it's cache, I found the line in the source code where the 10000 is implemented but since I don't understand the impact of the hashing algorithms on a much larger cache I've feared changing it in code. I'm just going to have to dig into the cache.c and see if I can learn it.

Comment: Is my base understand that a dnslookup from an lan devices would be: dnsmasq, /etc/hosts, then upstream DNS servers?  I am not using the no-hosts parm.

Comment: @ZacWolf Sorry, I cannot answer this. Some years ago I used `dnsmasq` with a relatively small number of `address=` lines in its config file, I used `/etc/hosts` for my local domain only.

Comment: Christopher, is that via adding: server=/servername/ip entries in the dnsmasq conf? Also are you using dnssec?

Comment: @Christopher I have RAM to spare, which is why I was interesting the idea of dnsmasc caching the full 466125 entries from the energize.pro lists.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the two options:

1: Adding `addn-hosts=hosts.conf` [from Energized.pro] to `dnsmasq.conf`
Added 3 second (not millisecond) to a dig request from the same machine running dnsmasq
I saw approximately the same result time for a domain whether in the `hosts.conf` list or not.

2: `dnsmasq.conf` with **no** `no-hosts` parameter added, but with the Energized.pro hosts appended to my `/etc/hosts` file added no additional lookup time: 72ms for dig of a different domain (dnssec adding the delay), with 0ms repeating the dig of the same domain; likewise doing a dig of a domain in the `/etc/hosts` correctly reported 0.0.0.0 in 0ms first or subsequent times.

Based on my reading, `/etc/hosts` is loaded into memory at startup. So it would seem that dnsmasq is accessing that memory resident `/etc/hosts` data without storing it in its own process memory, whereas utilizing `addn-hosts=hosts.conf` does. The first dig taking 72ms and the second dig (being in the cache) taking 0ms, so the cache parm used in `dnsmasq.conf` is used strictly for caching lookups, and not used for `addn-hosts=hosts.conf` data, so I have no idea where that is being stored (but for 3 seconds, a tmp file maybe?!?)

I'll update if I find more in the code.